# How can I access each element of a list of input matrices on a shiny server?

Tags: r, matrix, shiny, output, reactive

I am trying to access output values inside the server on my shiny app.
The values are inputed by the user in a loop: depending on the number 'n_matrizes', the user inputs 'n_matrizes' number of matrices. The server then collects all these matrices in a list, using lapply:

```
lapply(1:(n_matrizes()),function(i){
             matrixInput(inputId = paste0("W_",i),
                         label = paste("Matriz espacial de ordem", i),
                         value = matrix(0,nrow=n_radares(),ncol=n_radares()))})
```

In the server, I need to access each of these matrices on the list. I've tried using `reactive` and `reactiveValues` but since I'm new to this programming, I haven't succeeded.

On normal R coding, I have done this before:

To create the list of matrices:

```
w_1 <- matrix(1,nrow=4,ncol=4)
w_2 <- matrix(2,nrow=4,ncol=4
w_3 <- matrix(3,nrow=4,ncol=4
W <- list(w_1,w_2,w_3)
```

To access one of them:

```
W[[1]]
```

How do I do that on the shiny server?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In general, you can access the matrices with `input$W_1` etc. Because they are reactive values, you can only access them in a reactive context (e.g. `reactive`, `observeEvent`). Can you elaborate a bit on your usecase and maybe give some (mock) code what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can access any input element within the server using it's `inputId`. If the `inputId` is a combination of strings and numbers you already know to use `paste()`. Let us say you have a list of widgets with a name pattern `W_1`, `W_2`, `W_3` ... you can access them easily with `input[[paste0("W_", 1L)]]`. Of course, you can replace the number by any integer variable.

From your sample I assume that you have a function that creates several instances of `inputMatrix`. Your code also suggests that when I call that function repeatedly, I get multiple instances with the same `inputId` `W_1`, `W_2`, .... That will cause an error. Make sure your `inputId`s are **unique**.